# Ajax request URL with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am making an HTTP request with the Google Maps API and I have to pass in parameters (adresses/coordinates):

```
 $.ajax({
        url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + $("#origin").val() + '&destinations=' + $("#destinations").val() +'&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyASanevdiCI4t1h8LMf5FgWHMD52K3QeB0',
        type: 'GET',
        success : function(data){
        //My code
        }
    });
```

I was wondering if there was any better cleaner way to do this. I know string concatenation is an option, but I want to know if I have any other options. I just feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we examine the [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), we can conclude that **what you have is standard and clean**. Mostly. I'll say a few things though:

- Instead of the `success` key, you could choose to use `.done()`, as in:

  ```
  $.ajax({
   // parameters
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
   // success
  });
  ```
- To evade string concatenation, you could use a custom string formatting function. JavaScript doesn't have a string format method, so you'll have to add one in, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/3234482). Then you can code like this:

  ```
  var mapsURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyASanevdiCI4t1h8LMf5FgWHMD52K3QeB0';
  ```

  then

  ```
  url: mapsURL.format($("#origin").val(), $("#destinations").val());
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to put your query string into the **data** property of your **XHR** request in order to clean up your request as well.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    origins: $("#origin").val(),
    destination: $("#destinations").val(),
    mode: "driving",
    key: "AIzaSyASanevdiCI4t1h8LMf5FgWHMD52K3QeB0"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```